# How to get everything after an extension unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file name like
filename.txt.zip_20180202_30291_233

In script variable i will have filename in a variable and extension in variable 
like

```
echo $fileprefix
filename
echo $filesuffix
.txt.zip
```

How do i rename the file to below one ? Moving everything after extension to before extension ? (Note: there could be any numbers after extension )

filename_20180202_30291_233.txt.zip

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

prefix='filename'
suffix='.txt.zip'

name='filename.txt.zip_20180202_30291_233'
newname="$prefix${name#$prefix$suffix}$suffix"

echo mv "$name" "$newname"
```

This would output

```
mv filename.txt.zip_20180202_30291_233 filename_20180202_30291_233.txt.zip
```

The parameter substitution `${name#$prefix$suffix}` removes `$prefix$suffix`, i.e. `filename.txt.zip`, from the start of `$name`, which gives you `_20180202_30291_233`.  This is then prepended with `$prefix` and appended with `$suffix` to create `$newname`.

Looping over all files that matches `"$prefix$suffix"*` in the current directory and renaming all:

```
for name in "$prefix$suffix"*; do
    newname="$prefix${name#$prefix$suffix}$suffix"
    echo mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

The `echo` is there for protection. Remove it once you are certain the code will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_orig=filename.txt.zip_20180202_30291_233
fileprefix=filename
filesuffix=.txt.zip
file="${file_orig#$fileprefix}"
file="${file#$filesuffix}"
file="$fileprefix$file$filesuffix"
echo "$file"
```

```
filename_20180202_30291_233.txt.zip
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion